# ERROR: unknown key name 'CONCAT_WS' in sphinx query

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, sphinx, concat-ws

I am new in sphinx and mysql and trying to execute simple query as shown below

```
sql_query               = \
                (SELECT users.id AS uid, \ 
                CONCAT_WS(' ', users.fname, users.lname, users.email) AS data \
                FROM users) \
                UNION ALL \
                (SELECT documents.id AS diid, documents.description \
                FROM documents);
```

But I am getting below error CONCAT_WS on indexing command

> ERROR: unknown key name 'CONCAT_WS' in /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf
>   line 12 col 26. FATAL: failed to parse config file
>   '/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf'

Answer (score 1):

You have a space AFTER the slash on the line before

```
            (SELECT users.id AS uid, \ 
                             ---------^
```

So Sphinx thinks the CONCAT_WS is starting a whole new line, rather than just continuing the line before.

The slash shouldn't have ANYTHING after it - as it's meant to be 'escaping' the end of line itself.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, will test and get back to you. Thanks